# Outlook 2010 VSTO AddIn does not load after automatic installation - only after manual execution

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have created a little VSTO AddIn for Outlook 2010 and a setup project to install it (like described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/10/01/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-2-of-2.aspx) and in other tutorials)

The installation runs fine: All prerequisits are installed and all registry keys are present (also the manifest key is correct and not corrupted).
However, the AddIn does not show up in Oulook after the installation. Not as inactive or anything else, it simply does not show up.

If I now go to the installation directory (AppData\Roaming\My Company\MyAddIn) and execute the .vsto file, it is installed and loaded in Outlook on startup without any problems.

I also signed the AddIn and installed the certificates (I dont get any certificate warning when executing the VSTO file directory).
After I install the AddIn manually, it shows up twice in Windows' list of installed programs: The setup application and now the AddIn itself.

Does anyone has an idea what I am missing? I have reviewed a lot of similar questions but none solved my specific issue.

Thanks and lot and best regards!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to register the AddIn dll with regsrvr32 or something similar.
Ensure it's done in your installer.

Comment: I haven't read anything like this in any of the tutorials. How would you suggest to do this during installation? Is there an option fot this in the setup project?